# Modify Tomcat example

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm modifying the examples coming with Tomcat 7.0.14. Tomcat is deployed at localhost:8080. I can see the page http://localhost:8080/examples/ . however, after I changed webapps\examples\index.html, and reloaded http://localhost:8080/examples/, the changes didn't display. Anything else should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the host/context configured to reload?

start/stop the server?

delete /work

but it should show the changes.  is the browser caching the page? try refreshing with ctrl+f5 rather than just f5.

Answer (score 1):

In this directory below:

> webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes

The java source codes have already been compiled to .class file.
Maybe that causes the problem.